# modulus function with complex arguments

Tags: complex-numbers

How to calculate a mod function (division remainder) between two complex arguments?

The arguments could be decimal or negative.

I looking for an algorithm (for solving) to implementing in my app.

for example:
(91.8i) mod (5+2i)

Comment: How is $$z\pmod w$$ defined when $z$ and $w$ are complex numbers?

Comment: yes, at least one of them can be a complex number?

Comment: "yes, at least one of them can be a complex number?" Not my question.

Comment: Sorry, I may not have understood your question (I'm not a mathematician). What do you mean by "How is Z (mod W) defined"?

Comment: I mean "How is Z (mod W) defined?"

Comment: Maybe you didn't understand my question. Take a look at the example of the question (Z=91.8i, W=5+2i).

Comment: Maybe I understood perfectly what you wrote but am pointing out (three times now) the fact that there exists no canonical definition of "modulo a complex number" (or rather, that one could concoct one such definition but that it is probably not the one you have in mind) and that, consequently, you should provide one such definition before your question can even make sense. Do you know the definition of "modulo" a given number, on the real line? Do you see why the generalization fails in the complex plane?

Comment: Don't be angry :) as I mentioned I'm a developer, not a mathematician. I looking for 'mod' algorithm for my app. If there no one definition for that, I prefer to use the same definition as [Wolfram Alpha](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=%2891.8i%29+mod+%285%2B2i%29).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's one interpretation: $${91.8i\over5+2i}={(91.8i)(5-2i)\over(5+2i)(5-2i)}={459i+183.6\over29}=15i+6+{24i+9.6\over29}$$ so the remainder is $${(5+2i)(24i+9.6)\over29}$$

Comment: Thanks Gerry, I also get this result. 
But why [Wolfram Alpha](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=%2891.8i%29+mod+%285%2B2i%29) has a different result?

Comment: I don't know. What definition does Wolfram Alpha use?

Comment: I already understand that there is no standard definition for this case. Even different scientific calculators can provide different results. Thanks!

Comment: The built-in method of expressing thanks is to "accept" the answer by clicking in the check mark, if you are satisfied with the answer.